# Why do Netbeans 7 recommend using Source Level 6 for all Java EE 6 projects?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

When I create a new enterprise application project in Netbeans 7.2.1, the IDE shouts out a recommendation: "Source Level 6 should be used in Java EE 6 projects".

Have a look at this screenshot:

[Screenshot of Netbeans IDE 7.2.1 http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/Qs9Doh.png](http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/Qs9Doh.png)

Why is this practice recommended? Any reason not to follow the advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to produce portable applications, Java SE 6 is the base on which Java EE 6 is defined.

From [JSR 316: JavaTM Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 (Java EE 6) Specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316):

> EE.2.4.1Container Requirements
>
> This specification requires that containers provide a Java Compatible™
>   runtime environment, as defined by the Java Platform, Standard
>   Edition, v6 specification (Java SE).

However, if you have a vendor-specific target Java EE 6 platform built on a newer version of Java you should often use its JDK as the target.

There's a trade-off between portability and being able to take advantage of container-specific features in enterprise development. NetBean's conservative recommendation is the correct option for those who don't know enough to make their own decision.